# Why is this Java Calendar comparison bad?

Tags: java

I'm having an inexplicable problem with the Java Calendar class when I'm trying to compare to dates. I'm trying to compare to Calendars
and determine if their difference is > than 1 day, and do things bases on that difference or not. But it doesn't work.

If I do this with the two dates:

```
    String currDate = aCurrentUTCCalendar.getTime().toString();
    String localDate = aLocalCalendar.getTime().toString();
```

I get these results:

```
    currDate  = "Thu Jan 06 05:58:00 MST 2010"
    localDate = "Tue Jan 05 00:02:00 MST 2010"
```

This is correct.

But if I do this:

```
    long curr = aCurrentUTCCalendar.getTime().getTime();
    long local = aLocalCalendar.getTime().getTime();
```

I get these results: ( in milliseconds since the epoch )

```
    curr  = -125566110120000 
    local =  1262674920000
```

Since there is only about a 30 hour different between the two, the magnitudes are vastly different, not to mention that annoying negative
sign.

This causes problems if I do this:

```
long day = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000; // 86400000 millis, one day

if( local - curr > day )
{
    // do something
}
```

What's wrong? Why are the getTime().toString() calls correct, but the getTime().getTime() calls are vastly different?

I'm using jdk 1.6_06 on WinXP. I can't upgrade the JDK for various reasons.

Comment: "I'm having an inexplicable problem with the Java Calendar class" - you're using java.util.Calendar. That's the explanation. More seriously, could you provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? It does sound very odd...

Comment: How did you create the `aCurrentUTCCalendar`?

Comment: Ummm, is the answer "Use Joda Time"? I've never done any Java, but I did see Jon Skeet in London :)

Comment: Indeed, a SSCCE would be nice: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Do you experience the same problem when calling the Calendar's `getTimeInMillis()` method? http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()

Comment: The problem is in the aCurrentUTCCalendar variable, Jan 6th 2010 is not Thurday!!

Comment: @medopal: Jan 6th 2010 BC(E) is a Thursday :)

Comment: @Fortega, that could explain the negative sign!!

Comment: I didn't use an sscce because it was not necessary. The two calendars show the correct date when I use getString(), and show the wrong time when I use getTime(). Frankly, I put too much in there as it is.

Yes, I tried getTimeInMillis() with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the JodaTime class. Thanks for the intro, it was way easier to get the results that I wanted instead of Java's hard-to-use stuff.

I leave this as one of the oddities of those Java.Util.Date and Java.Util.Calendar classes.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Your currDate  is "B.C.E. 2010-01-06" ([Before Common Era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Before_common_era)), which is 4019 (2x2010 - 1) years ago.

Try this:

```
public class StrangeDate {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date d = new Date(-125566110120000L);
    System.out.println(d.toString());
    //prints 'Thu Jan 06 13:58:00 CET 2010' in my locale

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4019);

    System.out.println(c.getTime().toString());
    //prints 'Wed Jan 06 13:58:00 CET 2010' in my locale
  }

}
```

The question is: what did you do to get this `aCurrentUTCCalendar`?

Comment: +1, how did you figure that out! `aCurrentUTCCalendar` became the mysterious variable

Comment: the -125566110120000 indicates a date which is a very long time ago :)

Comment: Then why, when I do toString(), do I get a correct representation of the date? It's the fact that the string representation is correct, but the millis are completely whacked that bothers me.

Comment: Because it IS 2010-01-06, but 'before Christ'. So the string representation is correct. The ERA is not taken into account in the toString() method. So the representation of the (very old) date IS correct...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the fact that it prints "Tue 5" and "Thu 6" indicates something's wrong with your date creation ?

ps : irrelevant, but instead doing cal.getTime().getTime(), you could do cal.getTimeInMillis()

Comment: No, that's localization in action.

Comment: getTimeInMillis() does the same thing.